# Tinyscrollbar for Mobiles

Tags: mobile, tinyscrollbar

According to [Tinyscroll's website](http://www.baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/), mobile scrolling is supposed to work. Under options you see:

> `invertscroll: false` -- Enable mobile invert style scrolling.

Has anybody actually gotten this to work? Help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

My code is the standard HTML set up with my options configured as:

```
$.tiny.scrollbar = {
        options: {
                axis       : 'y'    // vertical or horizontal scrollbar? ( x || y ).
            ,   wheel      : 40     // how many pixels must the mouswheel scroll at a time.
            ,   scroll     : true   // enable or disable the mousewheel.
            ,   lockscroll : true   // return scrollwheel to browser if there is no more content.
            ,   size       : 'auto' // set the size of the scrollbar to auto or a fixed number.
            ,   sizethumb  : 'auto' // set the size of the thumb to auto or a fixed number.
                                             ,   invertscroll  : true // enable scrolling for mobiles

        }
    };
```

Comment: I've extended my post above...

Comment: Yes, it did work for me. And my code is no different from yours.

Answer (score 0):

It is scrollInvert not Invertscroll.  If you don't believe me open up the jquery.tinyscrollbar.js and it will be in the second function.